# Type signature of comparison function object

Tags: c++, functor

How can I use a comparison function object type in a method signature? Eg., this is all fine:

```
struct compInt {
    bool operator() (const int a, const int b) { return a < b; }
};  

set<int,compInt> s1; 

// Actually this is no good, but removing it would obfuscate
// the accepted answer:
set<int> s2(compInt);
```

*[The last one compiles but it's a function declaration, s2 turns out not to be a container]*.

But I want to do this:

```
void func (____ x)
{
    set<int> s(x);
}
```

I do not want to do this:

```
template<typename C>
void func (C& c)
{
    set<int> s(c);
}
```

And `function<bool(const int,const int)>` does not work.  I tried making `compInt::operator()` virtual so I could do this:

```
void func (compInt& ci)
```

And pass in derived objects, but in fact `set<int> s(ci)` then fails to compile (which I'm almost grateful for, because it is a horrid hack).

Comment: ? I do not understand. You want to do `typedef int ____;`? 
So you want `template<typename C>
void func()
{
    set<int, c> s;
}`? `I do not want to do this:` why? `And function.... does not work` - what is `function`? Is `function` a typo for `func`? `hen fails to compile` - please post the exact full code that "fails to compile" including relevant `#include`s, error message, compiler version, options, etc. Please create an [MCVE].

Comment: You want your comparison function object to be dynamic? You could have a comparison function object that wraps a std::funcion<> and calls it inside.

Comment: please next time (you could still do it here) include a [mcve] and the error message.

Comment: @BogdanPetrica I guess I am wishing that this was already the case, ie., "comparison object", which is pretty clearly defined conceptually, could have a concrete signature.  I think I see now why that cannot be, but it seems a historical burden to the language that these aren't just straight functors -- which you could still then use a comparator obj if you need to maintain state, since they fit `function<bool(int,int)>`, but I would guess the stateless function pointer would be the far more common case.

Comment: not sure if I understand your comment, but maybe you are looking for this: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare. Specifiying any more than that would be too restrictive. Such named requirements have been around in c++ since long time already, but only with concepts in c++20 they are really first class citizens

Comment: cannot help myself, i am bit disturbed by your claim that `set<int> s1(compInt);` would be "all fine". I suppose it is a typo and should be `set<int> s1(compInt());`. Maybe we can ask eerorika to adjust their answer and fix the typo? because otherwise it is a nice question

Comment: however, answer is already given and accepted, maybe just leave it be...

Comment: @KamilCuk `function` = https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function As per previous comment I wish those were around when the STL was written.

Comment: @idclev463035818 Thanks for latching on that, I've edited.  Using `compInt()` as the param to `set` actually doesn't compile, whereas `compInt` does -- but it does not produce a useable set.  I hadn't gotten to that part yet, lol.  It is of course a (localized) function signature and not a container initialization. >_<

Comment: please take care not to invalidate answers by editing your question. The important part of my comment was "Maybe we can ask eerorika to adjust their answer". Unless the answer is also "fixed" i'd rather fix the "all fine". if you edit part of answers in your quesiton that part of the  answer looks pointless

Comment: I know.  I made that explicit in the question -- I did not remove the red herring `set<int> s2(compInt);`, I just labelled it correctly.  Part of the reason the original question might have been confusing is that I did not realize I was declaring a function there, not initialising a set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> set<int> s1(compInt);
> ```

This declares a function whose return type is `set<int>`.

> ```
> set<int> s(x);
> ```

This declares a local variable of type `set<int>`. The comparator type is not deduced from the argument, but instead the default template argument is used. As such, `compInt` is not used as the comparator, so you cannot pass an instance of `compInt` to the constructor.

You can use:

```
void func (compInt x)
{
    std::set<int,compInt> s(x);
```

> I tried making compInt::operator() virtual so I could do this:
>
> ```
> void func (compInt& ci)
> ```

Polymorphic comparator would be quite problematic. Set stores the object by value, so passing into the function through a reference would not help. You would need to use type erasure: Define a wrapper comparator that takes a polymorphic comparator as constructor argument, stores it in dynamic storage, and delegates the call operator to the stored polymorphic comparator. Then use the wrapper type as the template argument of the set.

Comment: ".... you cannot pass `x` to the constructor" I only read about new features of type deduction recently, so I am not sure, doesnt it work with C++17 and beyond, because the type of the comparator is deduced from `x` ?

Comment: @idclev463035818 It could work if set had an appropriate type deduction guide. It apparently does not. I don't know why.

Comment: I facepalmed myself about this after writing the question, but I was still determined to get a catch-all type signature for the purely-conceptual-in-C++-yet clearly definable "comparison object".... Now I'm realising it's because the type of a class can only be the class itself or a base, and `set` is a template, so the "comparison object" is only implicitly defined by behaviour.  Guess that should have been obvious...

Comment: the question is a bit confusing by claiming that things would be "all fine", so [I had to convince myself](https://wandbox.org/permlink/YnTdgNsNRWdUInlj)

Comment: @idclev463035818 I thought about it a bit, and I think that because the template argument has a default, adding a deduction guide could in theory break existing code that passes comparator of different, but convertible type.

Comment: I actually did not *want* truly polymorphic comparators, although I suppose this makes them possible.  The reason I tried the base class approach was so that I could have something to replace `_______` in the method params.  The context is objects that could be sorted various ways (lexical field a, lexical field b, timestamp, etc.), and the client provides this.  I'm now thinking a variation on your last idea might be best -- take a plain functor arg, and in the body wrap that in a comparison object proper.

Answer (score 0):

Eeroiki got me going in the right direction. What I eventually settled on was this (note the objects to be compared actually aren't ints, and a wide range of comparators could be applied to them).

```
using intCompFunc = std::function<bool(const int,const int)> 

struct compInt {
    intCompFunc comp;
    bool operator() (const int a, const int b) const {
        return comp(a, b);
}

void foo (intCompfunc icf)
{ 
    compInt ci { icf };
    std::set<int,compInt> s1(ci);
}
```

Which means the user can pass in any kind of functor, eg. a lambda:

```
foo([] (const int a, const int b) { return a < b; });
```

My confusion stems from why it isn't this way in the first place, which I think is really a historical problem (there were no C++11 functors when the STL was written).  OTOH, using a base type instead of a template parameter does introduce some runtime overhead.

Comment: it isnt really a historical problem. Note that `std::function` is quite a beast. It gives you an object that can hold all kinds of callables. This comes at a cost and often you do not need it. Eg If need only one certain type of comparator then the overhead of `std::function` is not needed